# How to suppress all JavaScript runtime errors?

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, suppress

How can I suppress all JavaScript runtime error popups, from the programmers side?

Comment: You can try to wrap your whole code into a `try...catch` block. But it is better to fix errors ;)

Comment: sometimes there is not possibility to use  `try...catch`, for example if some external library throws errors. Using window.onerror event is the solution in this case, see my answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To suppress all JavaScript errors there seems to be a `window.onerror` event. 
If it is replaced as early as possible(e.g. right after the head) by a function which returns true - there will be no error popups, which is quite useful after debugging is done.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber) {  
        // code to execute on an error  
        return true; // prevents browser error messages  
    };
</script> 
...
```

Error Logging is possible too, as explained [here](http://mattsnider.com/javascript/window-onerror-event/)

Comment: _The HTMLDocumentEvents4::onerror event fires for run-time errors, but not for compilation errors. In addition, error dialog boxes raised by script debuggers are **not** suppressed by returning true._ from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff976266(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work for Angular 2.x+ apps - likely due to the Angular handling the errors itself.

Answer (score 3):

I made a little script for suppressing an error like "@" does in PHP.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardo_ciaccio/coj2f4w4/).

```
var at = function( test ) {
    try {
        if(typeof test === "function") return test();            
        else return test || null;        
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    }
};
```