# Comments Javascript console firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Does anyone know if could be possible to comment the messages javascript that appear in a console firefox? i mean if i wanted for example hide this error messages, there is an way to hide it?
[image: enter image example errors]

Comment: There are few ways to hide those nasty messages. The best is by fixing actual error in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn off the JS button (Log Javascript Exception) on the ribbon on top of the Developer Toolbar.

These errors are just for development purposes and make the users and developers aware of what's wrong with what.

Comment: ok...they ask me self to hide this type of error when we try to open app...but in the meanwhile that has to be resolved.. doesn't exist a brutal method for hide this error on the console notwithstanding have console(js) opened?

Comment: You can use _onerror_ event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120290/how-to-suppress-all-javascript-runtime-errors