# Handle the client errors and prevent them from showing in browser console for a specific library?

Tags: javascript, http, error-handling, bad-request

I am using a library and in some cases it returns "400 http bad request",and the browser console print it. How can I handle the client errors and prevent them from showing in browser console for a specific library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120290/how-to-suppress-all-javascript-runtime-errors

Comment: you can't - because it's a network request that "fails", and there's no way you can prevent me from seeing that

Comment: but can i catch the error with javascript somehow?

Comment: did you click on my link? :) It's the same principle.

Comment: no, because it's a network error that will always be reported in the network console